# How to set a build stack for ionic-cloud cli builds?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli, ionic-appflow, ionic-cloud

I'm trying to build an ionic web-build to be [deployed through AppFlow live updates, using the ionic-cloud cli](https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/cli/live-updates), by running:

```
ionic-cloud build web --app-id=12345678 --commit=35d97a73bf3bb7144bcc9473bcc9b6e0fb2ec500
```

I'm getting an npm incompatability error, because it is building my project for the latest [ionic-stack](https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/build-stacks), while my build is targetting an earlier 2022.07 stack:

[image]

How can I specify the build stack when running ionic-cloud build command manually?

Answer (score 0):

Info about specifying the build stack using the ionic-cloud-cli for web builds can be found by typing `ionic-cloud build web -h`:

```
ionic-cloud build web
This command creates a web build on Appflow. While the build is running, it prints the remote build log to the terminal.

Usage:
  ionic-cloud build web [flags]

Aliases:
  web, live-update, web-preview

Examples:
ionic-cloud build web --app-id=a1234bc --commit=a9eb85e
ionic-cloud build web --app-id=a1234bc --commit=a9eb85e --web-preview
ionic-cloud build web-preview --app-id=b3456cd --commit=4c511f1 --environment="My Custom Environment Name"

Flags:
      --app-id string          Appflow app id [required]
    
      ******
      --build-stack string     Target platform ("Linux - 2023.10" / "Linux - 2023.06" / "Linux - 2023.04" / "Linux - 2022.10" / "Linux - 2022.07"), defaults to latest stack
      ******

      --commit string          Commit sha [required]
      --detached               Asynchronously run appflow build (default: false)
      --env env-file           Variables to expose to your build. Variables defined this way override those loaded using the env-file flag. Example: --env VAR=value
      --env-file stringArray   Files declaring environment variables to expose to your build. Variables from later files overwrite variables from earlier files.
      --environment string     The name of the predefined Appflow Environment to expose to your build
  -h, --help                   help for web
      --secret stringArray     Secrets to expose to your build. Example: --secret VAR=value
      --web-preview            Enable web preview
      --zip                    Download zip file
      --zip-name string        Download zip and rename file. Example: myapp.zip
```

So the use a specific build stack, run:

```
ionic-cloud build web --build-stack="stack-string" --app-id=12345678 --commit=35d97a73bf3bb7144bcc9473bcc9b6e0fb2ec500
```

For stack 2022.07 that is in the question, run:

```
ionic-cloud build web --build-stack="Linux - 2022.07" --app-id=12345678 --commit=35d97a73bf3bb7144bcc9473bcc9b6e0fb2ec500
```